# How to stop a service in block method in Android?

Tags: android

1. I run the code and get the following result, but I hope that the App can run at the order "A" -> "Service OnDestroy" -> "B" -> "C", how can I do ?
2. In **My Way 2** section,  I try to place the code into the function `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {}`, it's OK , it ran at the order "A" -> "Service OnDestroy" ->"B" ->"C",
   I don't konw why the way can success, I don't know if the way is good way!

**Result**

11-13 10:04:32.137  27947-27947/info.dodata.screenrecorder E/My﹕ A

11-13 10:04:32.147  27947-27947/info.dodata.screenrecorder E/My﹕ B

11-13 10:04:32.157  27947-27947/info.dodata.screenrecorder E/My﹕ C

11-13 10:04:32.157  27947-27947/info.dodata.screenrecorder E/My﹕ Service OnDestroy

**UIAbou.cs**

```
public class UIAbout extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_about);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(UIAbout.this,bll.RecordService.class);
        startService(intent1);

        Button btnReturn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);
        btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("My", "A");

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(UIAbout.this,bll.RecordService.class);
                stopService(intent1);

                Log.e("My", "B");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.e("My", "C");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**RecordService.cs**

```
public class RecordService extends Service {

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Log.e("My","Service OnDestroy");
        super.onDestroy(); //It seems that the APP is OK if I remove this.
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }


}
```

**=======================My Way 1 ======================================**

I set a mark isServiceStoped to  monitor if Stop Service is finished, but my app is hang up after disply the result "11-13 11:31:23.107    7599-7599/info.dodata.screenrecorder E/My﹕ A"

**New UIAbout.cs**

```
public class UIAbout extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_about);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(UIAbout.this,bll.RecordService.class);
        startService(intent1);

        Button btnReturn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);
        btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("My", "A");

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(UIAbout.this, bll.RecordService.class);
                stopService(intent1);

                while (RecordService.isServiceStoped==false){
                    //It block 
                }

                Log.e("My", "B");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.e("My", "C");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**New RecordService.cs**

```
public class RecordService extends Service {

   public static boolean isServiceStoped=true;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Log.e("My", "Service OnDestroy");
        isServiceStoped=true;
        super.onDestroy(); //It seems that the APP is OK if I remove this.
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        isServiceStoped=false;
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }


}
```

***=====================My Way 2==========================================***

I try to place the code into the function `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {}`, it's OK , it ran at the order "A" -> "Service OnDestroy" ->"B" ->"C",

I don't konw why the way can success, I don't know if the way is good way

**The last UIAbout.cs**

```
public class UIAbout extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_about);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(UIAbout.this,bll.RecordService.class);
        startService(intent1);

        Button btnReturn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);
        btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("My", "A");

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(UIAbout.this, bll.RecordService.class);
                stopService(intent1);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("My", "B");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Log.e("My", "C");
                    }
                }, 1);


            }
        });

    }

}
```

**The last RecordService.cs**

```
public class RecordService extends Service {

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Log.e("My", "Service OnDestroy");
        super.onDestroy(); //It seems that the APP is OK if I remove this.
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you can't stop a service synchronously. stopService() is request to stop the service. It will stop sometime later, as soon as it can.
2. No, you can't remove super.onDestroy() from your onDestroy() method and still have it work properly.

Comment: Thanks, in fact, I have removed  super.onDestroy() , but the app worked well !

Comment: Is there a mark I can monitor if the servie stoped, if so, I can do this.

while（isServiceStoped==false）{
   //block 
  
}

if (isServiceStoped==true) {
    doSomething();    
}

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not control the timing to completely stop the running service. Use stopService() and the rest is out of your hands. You can use an handler to monitor is the service has stopped before moving to B although I am not sure why would you do it. Not a good practice.
2. Yeah you can remove super.onDestroy() in onDestroy but I would not advise you to do so. Your app may run but it will be leaving unwanted resources around.
   Here how onDestroy() looks like in the android SDK:

   ```
   @CallSuper
   protected void onDestroy() {
       if (DEBUG_LIFECYCLE) Slog.v(TAG, "onDestroy " + this);
       mCalled = true;

       // dismiss any dialogs we are managing.
       if (mManagedDialogs != null) {
           final int numDialogs = mManagedDialogs.size();
           for (int i = 0; i < numDialogs; i++) {
               final ManagedDialog md = mManagedDialogs.valueAt(i);
               if (md.mDialog.isShowing()) {
                   md.mDialog.dismiss();
               }
           }
           mManagedDialogs = null;
       }

       // close any cursors we are managing.
       synchronized (mManagedCursors) {
           int numCursors = mManagedCursors.size();
           for (int i = 0; i < numCursors; i++) {
               ManagedCursor c = mManagedCursors.get(i);
               if (c != null) {
                   c.mCursor.close();
               }
           }
           mManagedCursors.clear();
       }

       // Close any open search dialog
       if (mSearchManager != null) {
           mSearchManager.stopSearch();
       }

       getApplication().dispatchActivityDestroyed(this);
   }
   ```

*** Sample ***
There could be some compile errors, but you will get the idea.

```
public class UIAbout extends Activity {
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable checkServiceHandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_about);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(UIAbout.this,bll.RecordService.class);
        startService(intent1);
        Button btnReturn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);
        btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("My", "A");
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(UIAbout.this, bll.RecordService.class);
                stopService(intent1);
                checkServiceHandler = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  if(RecordService.isServiceStoped){
                       mHandler.removeCallbacks(checkServiceHandler );
                       somemethod();
                  } else{
                        mHandler.postDelayed(checkServiceHandler, 500);
                   }
                 }
               };
              mHandler.postDelayed(checkServiceHandler, 500);            }
        });
    }
  private void somemethod(){
                Log.e("My", "B");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("My", "C");  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see my modified Post.   I set a mark isServiceStoped to  monitor if Stop Service is finished, but my app is hang up after disply the result "11-13 11:31:23.107    7599-7599/info.dodata.screenrecorder E/My﹕ A",  at last the app crash, display application not responding error!

Comment: I modified my post, I try to place the code into the function new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {}, it's OK , it ran at the order "A" -> "Service OnDestroy" ->"B" ->"C",
I don't konw why the way can success, I don't know if the way is good way

Comment: Never use while(RecordService.isServiceStoped==false), it will block your UI. Use Handler instead.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me  a sample code using "Handler instead" ?

Comment: Thanks! I will try your code.  And more,   I try to place the code "Log.e("My", "B"); ..." into the function new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {}, you can see this in my midfied post, it's OK  , it ran at the order "A" -> "Service OnDestroy" ->"B" ->"C", I don't know why the way can success, I don't know if the way is good way

Answer (score 1):

**You should implement your code in a way that you don't care when exactly your service is destroyed.**

Anyway. If you really need the exact moment, you can fire an intent from your service using Android's broadcast system.

In your service:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(CONST_SERVICE_DESTROYED));
}
```

In your activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // your B here

        // your C here
    }
};
```

And you need to register and unregister your receiver like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(CONST_SERVICE_DESTROYED));
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

A good explanation and examples of Android's broadcast system can be found [here](http://codetheory.in/android-broadcast-receivers/)

Comment: Thanks! but I need to care when exactly my service is destroyed, because I need to handle data that service generated.

Comment: Well, broadcasting an intent when your service has collected the data will work for you. If you have any questions I'm here to answer :)